# Why do I get the error: "Using $this when not in object context in.........."

Tags: php, oop, this

$title = 'question' ;) Thanks in advance, I can't seem to figure it out.

```
class myClass {

    public $myVar = 'hello';

    public function myMethod() {
        echo $this->myVar;
    }

}
```

Comment: Seems the php engine told you, you are using `$this` the wrong way. $this is supposed to be used for assigning values, getting values. $this is a reference to itself, the current class.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice your reply until now. I was indeed using it the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing:

```
myClass::myMethod();
```

Or:

```
$foo = new myClass();
$foo->myMethod();
```

Comment: Actually the class I have is in a wordpress plugin. I just stripped it down to this since I kept getting the error.

A method of the class is being called from from a wordpress function (add_menu_page). I have not yet called the class from somewhere else. 

I assume I should do so?

How does it work when this wordpress function calls that method? Does it make a new instance of the class or does it just call the method within the class without actually initiating the class itself?

Comment: @JesperPurola I'm not familiar enough with wordpress, was it a static method before you stripped it down?

Post some more code, maybe the original? And the call?

Comment: Never mind, I have it figured out... The wordpress calls the method as a static. I have to make MyClass an object first. Your pointer helped me to to the answer!